# Setting csh path to a changing environment variable

Tags: shell, csh

Is there a way to set the `$PATH` in `csh` to another environment variable that I can change?

For example, say I put `$APPDIR` in my path:

```
setenv APPDIR "/home/user/version1/bin"
```

But then later I change `$APPDIR` to something else:

```
setenv APPDIR "/home/user/version2/bin"
```

Is there a way to put `$APPDIR` in the `$PATH` *without the variable being expanded* so that when I change `$APPDIR`, I don't have to update `$PATH` as well?

Comment: If the variable isn't expanded when you set `PATH` when would it get expanded so your variable's value would be seen/used?

Comment: Good point and maybe I'm asking the question a bit too specifically. I'm really after the behavior I'm describing although the mechanics may end up being different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You assign a string to `$PATH`, there is no way to dynamically insert something which will be evaluated on getting the value.

In fact, doing so might be considered a security problem, this is pretty much wat the recent bash "shell shock" vulnerability was all about ;-)

What you could do, is something like this in your `cshrc` or `tcshrc`:

```
if ( ! $?APPDIR ) setenv APPDIR 'default-appdir'
setenv PATH "${PATH}:${APPDIR}"
```

This will set `$APPDIR` to `default-appdir` only if it's empty; if you now change the value of `$APPDIR`:

```
setenv APPDIR new-appdir
```

and reload the config with:

```
source ~/.tcshrc
```

the value of `$PATH` will be updated.